# SSH connection client hangs

Tags: ssh

On the server I'm getting:

```
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user
Timeout, client not responding
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user
```

and on the client side I'm able to successfully authenticate and be presented with a prompt but I cannot type anything.

This is what I see before the connection gets closed:

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 100
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)
```

I am able to authenticate on the server with:

```
ssh -vvv <username>@localhost
```

and that works fine.

I have checked with another client and have the same issue (authenticates but cannot send). Is the router possibly causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post more of your output. "status: The following connections are open", for me was after I hit CTRL-D and logged out. This is what I got just before the MOTD and a prompt.

```
Authenticated to 55.55.55.55 ([55.55.55.55]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```